# Est-ce que la forme « Comparées à l’année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes » est correcte?

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Il s’agit d’une phrase que j’ai tirée de *BTB TERMIUM Plus* (le bureau de la traduction *TERMIUM Plus*).

Il me semble que si la proposition principale était introduite par *cette année* et que le participe s’y rapportait, la phrase serait correcte, à tout le moins elle aurait plus de sens. (Comparer des affaires à une année me paraît incohérent ou plutôt décousu, n’est-ce pas?) »

> Comparée à l’année passée, cette année nos affaires vont bien.

Si l’on préfère ne pas remanier la proposition principale, je pense qu’il serait de rigueur de recourir à des constructions comme *si l’on compare avec*, *en/par comparaison avec,* *comparativement avec* pour cet exemple-ci.

Ce qui donnerait, une fois la phrase en titre remaniée,

> Si l’on compare avec l’année passée, nos affaires vont bien.

Comment: Quel bureau de traduction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1- Comparées à l’année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes.
> 2- Comparée à l’année passée, cette année nos affaires vont bien.

Que ce soit la phrase du titre ou celle proposée en tant qu'amélioration elles sont toutes les deux construites sur la base d'une inspiration  par le principe métonymique qui fait de « année », non pas le concept primaire que l'on voit dans ce mot d'habitude mais quelque chose d'autre, et c'est un principe qui est très largement accepté.

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ann%C3%A9e)) − P. méton. La production de cette période. C'est une bonne année, une année moyenne, médiocre, une demi-année (Ac. 1798-1932).

- Ç'a été une bonne année pour la viticulture. (*Le rendement pendant la saison de l'année en question a été bon.*)
- Nous avons eu une mauvaise année dans le bâtiment. (*Les affaires dans le domaine de la construction pendant l'année donnée n'ont pas été bonnes.*)

Cependant, ce sont des constructions qui vont au-delà de ce que le principe permet: elles comprennent un mélange incongru.
-- 1: année (singulier) comparées (pluriel)
-- 2: année (métonymique), année (juste après, littéral)

*correction* :

- Comparée à l'année dernière cette année(-ci) est/a été bonne.
- Comparée à l’année passée, cette année(-ci) est/a été bonne.

On peut donc, sans remanier la principale et en préservant l'usage métonymique, donner à ces phrases une construction acceptable.

On peut effectuer une simple correction en abandonnant l'approche métonymique dans la première phrase.

- Comparées à celles de l’année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes.

> Si l’on préfère ne pas remanier la proposition principale, je pense qu’il serait de rigueur de recourir à des constructions comme si l’on compare avec, en/par comparaison avec, comparativement avec pour cet exemple-ci.
>
> - Si l’on compare avec l’année passée, nos affaires vont bien.

Oui, cela semble être aussi une option, mais l'usage de « année » doit encore être considéré comme métonymique, sinon on retrouve le reproche initial qui a été  fait : « Comparer des affaires à une année me paraît incohérent ou plutôt décousu ». « Si l'on compare quoi avec l'année passée ? » Évidemment il s'agit des affaires de la présente année.

- Par rapport à l'année passée, nos affaires vont bien.

Answer (score 4):

La phrase « **Comparées à** l’année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes » est idiomatique. C'est une simplification de la phrase :

> **Comparées à celles de** l'année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes (cette année).

On peut cependant aussi considérer que ***comparé*** doit être utilisé comme un adverbe, [ce qui est documenté comme un anglicisme](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2449)<sup>1</sup> et alors, en toute rigueur, il faudrait éviter de l'accorder :

> **Comparé** **à** l’année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes.

C'est à dire :

> **Par rapport** **à** l'année passée, nos affaires sont bonnes.

Idem pour :

> **Comparé** **à** l'année passée, cette année nos affaires vont bien.

C'est à dire:

> **Par rapport** à l'année passée, cette année nos affaires vont bien.

On retrouve cet usage adverbial (donc sans accord) dans cet article de [France 3 Bretagne](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/bretagne/cotes-d-armor/saint-brieuc/saint-brieuc-plus-coquilles-saint-jacques-quel-effet-prix-1570014.html):

> **Comparé à** l'an dernier, **les prix observés** en début de campagne, ont en effet légèrement fléchi. Près de 15 centimes de moins au kilo, qui devraient être compensés malgré tout, par des volumes plus importants.

Si on veut réellement faire une comparaison qui s'appuie sur ***comparé*** en tant qu'adjectif accordé, évitant ainsi les foudres de certains puristes, on peut remanier la deuxième partie de la phrase comme ceci :

> **Comparée** à l’année passée, cette année a été favorable à nos affaires.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>À l'image de :</sub>
   <sub>- ***Compared to** last year, we are in a much better situation where we can have livelihoods and lives both safe.* ([Mount Desert Islander](https://www.mdislander.com/maine-news/compared-to-last-year-business-down-for-most))</sub>
    <sub>- ***Compared to** last year, rates are up 26.1%, according to Truckstop.com.* ([CCJ](https://www.ccjdigital.com/economic-trends/article/15114910/spot-load-volume-returns-to-preholiday-levels))</sub>

Comment: «  ce qui est clairement un anglicisme » Ah, si tu comprends pourquoi ce serait un anglicisme, merci d'expliquer. Je ne vois pas d'où la BDL tire cette affirmation. « Comparé à » invariable n'avait pas l'air de choquer tant que ça au 19e siècle : [1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Bulletin_Documents_officiels_Statistique/kaA9AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22comparé+à%22&pg=PA394&printsec=frontcover) [2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Population_1807_comparé_à_1857_et_éte/b46WQwAACAAJ?hl=en)

Comment: @Gilles Effectivement, tes exemples montrent que ce n'est pas forcément nouveau, encore qu'on peut discuter sur le fait que dans les deux la référence est un nombre comparé à un autre, et que le masculin singulier peut donc alors aussi se défendre.